# combine two nested lists with removing duplicates

Tags: python, list, set

I want to combine two nested lists by removing the duplicates first.

```
list1 = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,5], [4,1], [9,6]]
list2 = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,5], [6,6], [0,2], [1,7], [7,7]]
results = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,5], [4,1], [9,6], [6,6], [0,2], [1,7], [7,7]]
```

my codes:

```
not_in_list1 = set(list2) - set(list1)
results = list(list1) + list(not_in_list1)
```

error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is it because `set` operation cannot be used in nested lists?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to use tuples instead of lists.  That way you can use a set to remove duplicates.  If you really want lists instead of tuples, you can convert back to lists after removing duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it because set operation cannot be used in nested lists?

Yes, this is because lists are mutable, so a list can change after creation, which means the hash used in the set can change.

However a tuple is is immutable, so you can use those in a set:

```
 list1 = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,5], [4,1], [9,6]]
 list2 = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,5], [6,6], [0,2], [1,7], [7,7]]
```

convert them to tuples:

```
 tuple1 = [tuple(l) for l in list1]

 tuple2 = [tuple(l) for l in list2]

 not_in_tuples = set(tuple2) - set(tuple1)
```

result for `not_in_tuples`:

```
 {(0, 2), (1, 7), (6, 6), (7, 7)}
```

and to combine them back to what you want in `results`:

```
results = list1 + list(map(list, not_in_tuples))
```

which yields:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1], [9, 6], [0, 2], [1, 7], [7, 7], [6, 6]]
```

**EDIT**

If interested in preserving order of both lists after adding them together:

```
list1 = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,5], [4,1], [9,6]]
list2 = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,5], [6,6], [0,2], [1,7], [7,7]]

intersection = set(map(tuple, list1)).intersection(set(map(tuple, list2)))

result = list1 + [list(t) for t in map(tuple, list2) if t not in intersection]
```

which yields:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1], [9, 6], [6, 6], [0, 2], [1, 7], [7, 7]]
```

Comment: thank! Can I just use `not_in_tuples = list(not_in_tuples)` to convert it back to list, and `results = list1 + not_in_tuples`? What is the advantage of using `map`?

Comment: @kay that gives you a list of tuples,  so it will be a combination list of lists combined with a list of tuples.

Comment: Under what circumstance `results = list1 + list(map(list, not_in_tuples))` does not preserve the order (i.e. `list1` precedes `not_in_tuples` in `results`)? I tried to use this line of code only, it seems preserve the order. Thanks!

Comment: @kay a `set` is unordered and `not_in_tuples` is a set, if you only care to have the items in `list1` in the front, but the items from `list2` added in any order after, then you are fine. However if you like to keep the ordering of the latter, then my edit should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert sub-lists [mutable] to tuples [immutable] and get the set

```
set([tuple(i) for i in list1+list2])
```

Output:

```
{(0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 7), (3, 5), (4, 1), (6, 6), (7, 7), (9, 6)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that is:

```
>>> list1 = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,5], [4,1], [9,6]]
>>> list2 = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,5], [6,6], [0,2], [1,7], [7,7]] 
>>> k = list1+list2 #We combine both the lists
>>> z = [] #Declare an empty list
>>>for i in k: #Loop through every element of the combined list
       if i in z: #If the element is already in the final list
           pass #Do nothing
       else: #If the element in the combined list is not not there in the final list
           z.append(i) #Append that element to the final list
>>>print z
>>>[[1, 2], [1, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1], [9, 6], [6, 6], [0, 2], [1, 7], [7, 7]]
```