# Merge and Remove Duplicate Items from Nested list

Tags: python-3.x, list

In a nested list (like the one below) that is continuous, I want to remove duplicate then merge where first  equal values.

```
product_list = [['product_1', 50, 33, 17], ['product_2', 10, 5, 0], 
['product_3', 9, 4, 5], ['product_2', 8, 4, 1]]
```

The target list is as follows:

```
aim_list = [['product_1', 50, 33, 17], ['product_2', 18, 9, 1], 
['product_3', 9, 4, 5]]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: this may answer your question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752026/combine-two-nested-lists-with-removing-duplicates

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your current code and output to the question.